# Finding an example path in a conservative vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, surface-integrals

If I know that in a conservative vector field has path independence, how would I go about finding an example path given the answer?

What does F.ds represent and how does it equal to pi?

Comment: Please use Math-Jax to formulate your questions.

Comment: Since $\vec{F}$ is conservative, there exists some scalar-valued function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\vec{\nabla} f = \vec{F}$. Find it and use path-independence.

Comment: just a comment: $F$ is not well-defined at points where $x=0$ or $y=0$, so it domain cannot be $\Bbb R^3$